# Is there a user-friendly editor for Karabiner complex modifications?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, karabiner

I have a large list of Karabiner complex modifications and it is hard to keep track of them all including conflicts, excluded applications, etc. From what I can tell the user is expected to edit `~/.config/karabiner/karabiner.json` by hand. However this isn't practical at all, since each modification definition ends up being quite verbose and I can only see 1-2 per screen. Is there some more efficient method that I'm missing? Or should I just write my own program to generate the `karabiner.json` file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not an editor, but an alternative, more concise and human friendly syntax for Karabiner is provided by [Goku](https://github.com/yqrashawn/GokuRakuJoudo).

Goku is a tool that lets you manage your Karabiner configuration with ease, leveraging on [EDN file format](https://github.com/edn-format/edn).

Comment: I actually found Goku but it was even more confusing than the JSON, so it didn't work for me. But since this technically answers my question, I'll accept it in case it helps others. Thank you!

Answer (score 14):

There's a simple web editor these days courtesy @genesy: https://genesy.github.io/karabiner-complex-rules-generator/

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  We're trying to find the best answers and those answers will provide **supporting info** as to why they're the best.  Answers should be self-contained so explain why you think the answer you provided will solve the problem or is better/more complete than the others already provided.  See [answer] on how to provide a quality answer. - From Review

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It answers the OP's question precisely and to the point. I have used this `genesy.github.io` and it is simply the only tool that meets the OP's specs. A comprehensive list of tools can be found here: https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/docs/json/external-json-generators/

Answer (score 6):

I found Goku (see answer by furins) and a few other tools but none seemed any easier than editing the JSON. In the end I wrote my own scripts which I'll share here.

There are two Python files:

- `decompose.py` takes a karabiner JSON and breaks it up into a many files and directories, so you can edit one rule at a time.
- `compose.py` takes these directories and rolls them into a single JSON that karabiner will accept.

I keep both the single JSON and the decomposed directories (as well as the script) in my dotfiles repo. When I want to alter a keybind, I create a directory for it (easiest method is to copy an existing one and modify) then do a roundtrip encode/decode. Eg.: `python compose.py; python decompose.py; python compose.py`.

After this my first step is to check `git diff` to see if my new rule has some error that broke the whole thing. If so, I have many options to revert the changes via `git` and try again. When done, I test the keybind with Karabiner-EventViewer and its intended use case, and commit.

The scripts are obviously limited and hacky, because they are for personal use (and I think the "proper" solution to this would be to just not use a Mac, har har). I suggest starting with a known-working JSON such as [PC-style shortcuts](https://ke-complex-modifications.pqrs.org/#pc_style_modifiers) so you can see how the existing rules work. They do work reasonably well, but some caveats:

- Each rule goes into a directory. The directory name is built from a number (to keep the rules from changing order and confusing git) and the name of the rule. Obviously rule names can have special characters, but directories cannot, so there's some funny normalization I had to do with that. It can be a bit fragile if you do fancy things with the rule name.
- I use PyCharm which has its own keyboard shortcut interceptor. Because of this, all rules are blacklisted from PyCharm at the composer/decomposer stage.

**compose.py:**

```
import json
from pathlib import Path

p_decomposed = Path('decomposed/')

# Load scaffold
p_scaffold = p_decomposed / 'scaffold.json'
with p_scaffold.open() as f:
    scaffold = json.load(f)

# Load rules
p_rules = p_decomposed / 'rules'
for p_rule in sorted(p_rules.iterdir()):
    if p_rule.stem.startswith('.'):
        continue
    print(p_rule)

    p_rule_json = p_rule / 'rule.json'
    with p_rule_json.open() as f:
        rule = json.load(f)

    p_manipulators = p_rule / 'manipulators'
    for p_manipulator in sorted(p_manipulators.iterdir()):
        with p_manipulator.open() as f:
            j = json.load(f)

        rule['manipulators'].append(j)

    profiles = scaffold['profiles']
    first_prof = profiles[0]
    complex_mods = first_prof['complex_modifications']
    rules = complex_mods['rules']
    rules.append(rule)

p_composed = Path('karabiner.json')
with p_composed.open('w') as f:
json.dump(scaffold, f, indent=4)
```

**decompose.py:**

```
import json
from pathlib import Path

with open('karabiner.json') as f:
    j = json.load(f)

profiles = j['profiles']
first_prof = profiles[0]
complex_mods = first_prof['complex_modifications']
rules = complex_mods['rules']

# Dump everything except the rules into a "scaffold file"
complex_mods['rules'] = []
with open('decomposed/scaffold.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(j, f, indent=4)


def normalize_rule_name(raw_name):
    """
    Normalize rule name by removing special characters, to make it suitable
    for use as a file name.
    """
    lowered = raw_name.lower()

    filtered = ''
    for c in lowered:
        if c.isalnum():
            filtered += c
        else:
            filtered += '-'

    while '--' in filtered:
        filtered = filtered.replace('--', '-')

    if filtered.endswith('-'):
        filtered = filtered[:-1]

    return filtered


def blacklist_pycharm(manipulator):
    pattern = "^com\\.jetbrains\\."

    if 'conditions' not in manipulator:
        return

    for c in manipulator['conditions']:
        if c.get('type', '') != 'frontmost_application_unless':
            continue

        if pattern not in c['bundle_identifiers']:
            c['bundle_identifiers'].append(pattern)


def process_manipulator(manipulator):
    """
    Gets applied to every manipulator before dumping it to a file.
    """
    result = dict(manipulator)

    blacklist_pycharm(result)

    return result


# Dump each rule to a separate file
for n, rule in enumerate(rules):
    # Normalize name
    desc = rule['description']
    desc_norm = normalize_rule_name(desc)

    # Pull out manipulators and save the rest
    manipulators = rule['manipulators']
    rule['manipulators'] = []

    p_rule = Path('decomposed/rules') / f'{n:03d}_{desc_norm}' / 'rule.json'
    p_rule.parent.mkdir(exist_ok=True)

    with p_rule.open('w') as f:
        json.dump(rule, f, indent=4)

    # Dump each manipulator
    p_manipulators = p_rule.parent / 'manipulators'
    p_manipulators.mkdir(exist_ok=True)
    for i, manipulator in enumerate(manipulators):
        p_m = p_manipulators / f'{i+1}.json'
        with p_m.open('w') as f:
            json.dump(process_manipulator(manipulator), f, indent=4)
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing your solution! I agree that Goku helps reducing the size of the document but not its complexity. By breaking the configuration file into smaller parts your solution helps a lot in keeping things simple. Correct me if I'm wrong but it seems that you can also leave e.g. a txt file in a decomposed folder to store some notes about the rule, that may be extremely useful.

Comment: @furins No problem - wish I had time to actually clean up and maintain this.

Comment: You are correct - it will only look at `rule.json` in the rule directory. However in the `manipulators` subdir, it will load everything - so if you put a non-json file in there, it will crash above `rule['manipulators'].append(j)`.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I've missed that line!

Answer (score 0):

I've tried every tool imaginable to alleviate the JSON management hell of Karabiner-Elements. I even went so far as to write my own Golang script that collects and watches all the JSONC, JSON, YAML and TOML files from a folder and then inserts the JSON into the ~/.config/karabiner/karabiner.json file.

Fortunately, I finally stumbled upon the tool https://github.com/evan-liu/karabiner.ts, which does everything I need it to do and does it perfectly. The website for it is https://karabiner.ts.keymaps.app/, and the best part is that you can try it out right away on Stackblitz, as there's a playground at https://karabiner.ts.keymaps.app/playground URL.

It's really handy because it abstracts some of the more advanced techniques involving variables into very simple commands. I'm referring in particular to doubleTap and singleTap, or modifierLayer and duoLayer, which are all advanced techniques that can be set up here with a single command.

With this tool available, it really baffles me that anyone would fuss and fret over the Goku and EDN file format.

Comment: The issue I would have is that it requires you to know a programming language - typescript in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I started making a GUI that supports the subset of actions I do regularly:
https://github.com/bilbofroggins/KarabinerKeyboard
It's rough around the edges at the moment but functional